# How to ensure SSL-only access without authorising in Java webapp?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I'm interested in ensuring that a couple of pages in a webapp are only accessible via https, but I don't want to authenticate the users.

Can I do this declaratively with security-constraints. or do I need to do something programmatically?

Any help appreciated, thanks folks

(Tomcat 5.5, servlet spec 2.3 - it's a legacy thing...)

Comment: +1 would like to see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `security-constraint` and set the `transport-guarantee` to `CONFIDENTIAL`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSL Redirect</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL
        </transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

[Servlet 2.3 Spec](http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr053/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have chance to place a Apache proxy in front of it? The SSL only connections would go through that and you would prevent direct access to you Tomcat instance from the outside network.